# What's the difference between a="$b" and a="value" where $b="value"?

Tags: php, ldap, variable-assignment

I'm doing some LDAP development in PHP and have run into some kind of, probably rookie, value assignment in PHP.

My issue is specific to LDAP_MODIFY, but is probably a generic issue.  I'm trying to update an attribute and the following attribute gives me an attribute not found error:

```
$email = 'Whitegon024@thedomain.org';
$attributes   = array( "userPrincipleName" => "$email");
```

But the following is successful:

```
$attributes = array( "userPrincipalName" => 'Whitegon024@thedomain.org') ;
```

If I do a `print_r($attributes);` of either I get:

```
Array
(
    [userPrincipleName] => Whitegon024@thedomain.org
)
```

Anyone have a clue?  I'm sure it's something super simple.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($attributes)`?

Comment: I'm glad some people learned something new from my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled principal as principle in your first attempt... it has nothing to do with how you are assigning your variables.

To clarify - `attribute not found` does not mean it's seeing a null value for the index `userPrincipalName` - the LDAP server is saying the index `userPrincipleName` itself doesn't exist as an attribute of a principal's LDAP record.

Comment: +1. I think this is the 4th question I've seen today where the error has been critical spelling failure.

Comment: I don't think the typo is the issue here, its the assigning of `$email` that isn't taking place.

Comment: @coder1984 the assignment is taking place, as shown by his `print_r($attributes)` showing the assignment taking place both ways.

Comment: @Darrrrrren: okies, I missed the `either`. @Salsero69: Happens... :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is parsing the double-quoted string for variables. Use single-quoted strings if you don't want the parsing. Also, even if you are using double-quoted strings, use `{$var}` instead of `$var`. Thus, you could also parse arrays `{$someArray['someIndex']}`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$attributes   = array( "userPrincipleName" => "$email");` to `$attributes   = array( "userPrincipleName" => $email);`

Comment: No. While what you said is probably a good idea, it's not necessary. PHP will automatically eval variables in double-quoted strings and get the right result, it's just marginally less efficient because of creating the new object.

Comment: How does this answer the question?